# Phpspreadsheet Search Between Columns

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Here's my code.

```
$highestColumn++;
 for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        for ($col = 'A'; $col != $highestColumn; ++$col) {
            $val = $sheet2->getCell($col . $row)->getValue();

            if($col < 'D'){
             //something
       }
   }}
```

In if, i'm getting A,B,C columns and getting other 'AA' 'BB' 'CC' 'CB' ... etc. And this is wrong solution for me. Is there any thing to do for this condition? I just want to see A,B,C columns in if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
$sheet->rangeToArray('BU3:CA3')[0];
```